# How to group by with only Time format in Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

i want to know that how to using the group by with only time format about datetime type.

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.tempDay, 108) as returnDay, b.qty from table1     as a inner join table2 as b on (a.id = b.id)
where a.id = 100
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), a.tempDay, 108), b.qty
```

Actually, tempDay is DateTime type.(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) in this case, i just want to groupping with only "HH:mm:ss" format with Linq.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Don't convert to strings when you want to compare *times*. Use `cast(tempday as time)` to get the time value. You could also create a separate column for the time that you could add to an index.

Answer (score 1):

```
var datesByTime = from d in dates
                  group d by d.TimeOfDay.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss") into g
                  select new { Time = g.Key, Dates = g.ToList() };
```

**dates** is collection of DateTime,  **DateTime** has property **TimeOfDay** which returns **TimeSpan** of that date, all you have to do Group By TimeOfDay. 
You need also **.ToString(@"hh:mm:ss")** to remove milliseconds.

Comment: The original SQL statement should be rewritten to reflect *this* LINQ statement - group by `cast(tempday as time)` and avoid text conversions

Comment: var datesByTime = from d in dates
                  group d by d.ToLongTimeString() into g
                  select new { Time = g.Key, Dates = g.ToList() };

Comment: Have you noticed the `entity-framework` tag? While this would be a good LINQ to Objects solution, in LINQ to Entities it simply generates the famous `NotSupportedException` - *"The specified type member 'TimeOfDay' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."*

Comment: Yes. i have using the entity-framework. and, it still not work.
    
group new { a, b }
by new { a.TempDay.Value.TimeOfDay.ToString("HH:mm"),             b.qty } into grp

when i tried like that i am still have problem. 
=> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.